# Docker container returns "unknown" for "uname -p" command

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I just installed a brand new Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS and also installed docker to run containers. I am facing some problems with it. A container will be used to run Jenkins and some of its jobs runs scripts to install Android NDK/SDK. These scripts are checking for the platform of the current machine using `uname -p` command. This command runs well on the host machine but it returns `unknown` in containers as follows:

```
lemonade@olympus:/$ docker info
Containers: 14
Images: 171
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Dirs: 199
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-38-generic
WARNING: No swap limit support
lemonade@olympus:/$ uname -a
Linux olympus 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lemonade@olympus:/$ uname -p
x86_64
lemonade@olympus:/$ docker run -ti java:7 /bin/bash
root@c6cdbb8a64fb:/# uname -p
unknown
root@c6cdbb8a64fb:/# uname -a
Linux c6cdbb8a64fb 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Does anyone knows why are the containers returning this? Some scripts (which are not coded by us) use this, as well as a lot of makefiles.

Thanks!

Comment: Inside your container, what gives `uname -m` and `file/bin/sh` ?

Comment: ```uname -m``` = ```x86_64``` 
```file/bin/sh``` = ```bash: file/bin/sh: No such file or directory```

Comment: Sorry for my typo it was `file /bin/sh`

Comment: Sounds like ```file``` does not exist:
```root@5dcaa6fd7cef:/# file /bin/sh```
```bash: file: command not found```
```root@5dcaa6fd7cef:/# file```
```bash: file: command not found```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason why `uname -p` fail with the `java:7` docker image but it seems to be due to the docker `debian` image. With the `ubuntu` docker image, everything is fine.

```
$ docker run debian uname -p
unknown

$ docker run ubuntu uname -p
x86_64
```

If you look at the Dockerfile dependencies for the `java:7` docker image you find out the following: [`java:7`](https://github.com/docker-library/java/blob/318ba809c9f0e3c7095b363c5a31409ee6880208/openjdk-7-jdk/Dockerfile)→[`buildpack-deps:jessie-scm`](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/scm/Dockerfile)→[`buildpack-deps:jessie-curl`](https://github.com/docker-library/buildpack-deps/blob/master/jessie/curl/Dockerfile)→[`debian:jessie`](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/blob/ea16605ec9cd86017a061fd123c71cc6b5e67f2c/jessie/Dockerfile)

The only thing that breaks the `uname -p` is the dependency on `debian:jessie`. What could do is to build your own `java:7` docker image, but making it depend on `ubuntu` instead of `debian`.

For that you would have to come up with a Dockerfile which is a merge of the ones used to make the `java:7` image.

Answer (score 3):

`uname -p` seems to be set to [unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname)  for a lot of linux distributions.

Though you don't control those scripts and make files you might want to submit bug reports upstream recommending they change their code to use `uname -m` instead if they are trying to detect `x86_64`, `armv7l`, `armv6l`, etc.